# Do Neumann eigenvalues on annulus converge to Neumann eigenvalues on ball?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian

Let $\mu_k(\alpha)$ be the $k$th eigenvalue of the Laplacian with Neumann boundary conditions on the annulus $B_1 \setminus \overline{B_\alpha}$, where $B_r \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ denotes the open ball of radius $r>0$ centered at the origin, $d \geq 2$. Let $\tilde{\mu}_k$ be the  $k$th eigenvalue of the Laplacian with Neumann boundary conditions on the ball $B_1$.

> Is it true that $\mu_k(\alpha) \to \tilde{\mu}_k$ as $\alpha \to 0$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

I'm quite sure that the answer is **yes**, but I can find neither a proper reference nor a simple and short argument for that.
(I know references which cover the Dirichlet boundary conditions, but not Neumann...)